# Spring batch Item reader to iterate over a rest api call

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch job, which needs to fetch details from rest api call and process the particular data on my side. My rest api call will have mainly the below parameters :

StartinIdNumber(offset)
PageSize(limit)

*ps: StartinIdNumber serves the same purpose as rownumber or "offset" in this particular API. The API response results are sorted by IdNumber, so by specifying a StartinIdNumber, the API will in turn perform a "where IdNumber >= StartinIdNumber order by IdNumber limit pageSize" in their DB query.*

It will return the given number of user details, I need to iterate through all the ids by changing the StartingIdNumber parameter for each request.

I have seen current ItemReader implementations of spring batch framework,which read through database or xml etc. But I didn't come across any reader which helps in my case. Please suggest a way to iterate through the user details as specified above .

Note : If I write my own custom item reader, I have to take care of preserving state (last processed "StartingIdNumer") which is proving challenging to me.

Does implementing ItemStream serves my purpose? Or is there any better way?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Implementing the ItemStream interface and writing my own custom reader served my purpose. It is now state-full as required for me. Thanks.

Comment: Would be helpful if you included an example of your implementation with this answer.

Comment: @mohan sammeta Please include an example of your answer when accepting it.

Comment: Along with comments above, this is quite useless and doesn't really help anyone finding this answer.